# How to "insert" text into UITextField?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, uitextfield

I'm trying to insert a text into a `UITextField`. But by insert, I mean replacing the character at cursor position with the new one (insert button's functionality on windows).

If I manually replace the incoming string and do `setText` (with `NO` returned to `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method), the cursor moves to the end of `textField`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the text as you have done previously and restore the position of your caret. Note that this can only be done with `UITextView` rather than `UITextField` (that would require a lot more unjustified work, unless you absolutely have to use `UITextField`):

```
NSRange selectionRange = myTextView.selectedRange;
myTextView.text = myNewText;
myTextView.selectedRange = selectionRange;
```

You have to note that it's a good idea to check the validity of `selectionRange` variable for new text - make sure that cursor position isn't greater than the new text length.

Comment: But `UITextField` doesn't have a `selectedTextRange` property. Only `UITextView` has `selectedRange`.

Comment: `UITextInput` protocol defines this property as *required*, and `UITextField` conforms to `UITextInput` protocol which makes it support the `selectedTextRange`

Comment: Sorry, but if you could have written that 3 lines of code in XCode you should have seen that it's not working.

Comment: You are right ugur, the solution is not as simple as it seems. After further investigation, it looks like UITextRange is a kind of an "abstract" class which UITextInput delegates have to implement. Which means UITextField has its own implementation of it. You could technically subclass UITextField and then deal with selection manually, but that is a lot of effort to implement. Instead, I would use a `UITextView` which allows setting selection ranges using a primitive `NSRange` - in that case my example would work. Sorry if this doesn't answer your question exactly the way you wanted.

Comment: Hm, thanks for your help. I think I should use UITextView for it. I just wanted UITextField way, but it seems there's no reason for that.

Answer (score 3):

For UITextField (iOS 3.2+), try:

```
[textField replaceRange:[textField selectedTextRange] withText:toInsert];
```